# Crystal report export functionality change pdf name

Tags: vb.net, printing, crystal-reports, export, rename

I am using crystal reports version 13.0.2000 in a .net 4.5 VB application. Currently when I try to print or export the report the pdf is saved with the name of the crystalreportviewer ID. How do I save with a custom name with out the crystal report viewer ID?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the DiskFileDestinationOptions. Something like:

```
Dim DiskOpts As New DiskFileDestinationOptions
DiskOpts.DiskFileName = "Your Export File"
```

And in the ExportOptions for the report:

```
.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile
.ExportDestinationOptions = DiskOpts
```

Comment: Thanks! how can I open the pdf in same tab without printing?

Comment: Please start a new thread for a new question.
If the first question is solved, please mark it as such.